# How to Remove Hosting Root directory name?

Tags: asp.net, url, subdirectory

i am using Godaddy to host multiple domains.  But once my website is hosted it shows the root directory name when I click any link inside my website..

Shouldn't the sub-directory act like the Root directory for my domain and hence not be visible in other URL paths inside my website?

Answer (score 0):

You should place the home page(or files which you don't want to see under sub-directory) in parent folder(root directory).